# Custom regex validation ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

I have a custom validator that is supposed to prompt the user to removed certain characters if found in the textbox. However, the validation is coming up even when there are no matching characters in the textbox.
I have tested the regex before implementing it in asp.net but it cannot pass the validation.

```
asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revHarmfulCharacters" runat="server" 
   ErrorMessage="Please remove these characters where present  >, <, /*, *\, --, |, {}" 
   ControlToValidate="txt_comment" ValidationExpression="[/^{}|<>(--)(/*)(*\/)(>=)]" 
   Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**The regular expression should be shown for this case**

[image: Image with character]

**But should not be shown for this case**

[image: Image without character]

**This is a test of the regex that I did**

[image: Regex test]

Comment: Why do you have brackets leading and ending here? `ValidationExpression="[/^{}|<>(--)(/*)(*\/)(>=)]" `

Comment: You probably want `ValidationExpression="^(?!.*(?:/\*|\*/|--|\|\||{})[^><]*$"`

Comment: ValidationExpression="[\^{}|<>(--)(\*)(*\/)(>=)]" Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression validation are written to match valid input. Since your regex pattern was not matched entire input string in both cases, so the error message is showed up in both cases.

You could try this pattern: `^[^/{}|<>(--)(/*)(*\/)(>=)^]+$`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the regex and test it.
Regex is `ValidationExpression="[\^{}|<>(--)(*)(*\/)(>=)]"` Try this

I try with this <bibin@212.com>. It is matched.

[image]

I try with this bibin@212.com. It is not matched.

[image]